# MySQL JOIN based on closest matching timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `user_subscription_history` a
LEFT JOIN `transaction` b ON b.tran_date=a.date_time
```

`b.tran_date` and `a.date_time` are both timestamps.  I'd like the join to return the closest matching.  Currently only returns if matching.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Avoid using the `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL. it's has several quirks you should be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the closest timestamp of another table:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, 
    row_number() over(
      order by abs(timestampdiff(microsecond, b.tran_date, a.date_time))
    ) as rn
  from user_subscription_history a
  cross join `transaction` b
) x
where rn = 1
```